# Create a website with or without a framework like TYPO3?

Tags: php, html, frameworks, typo3

I hope my question fits in stackoverflow, let me explain my problem:
I am using to program websites in Java, Javascript, HTML, CSS and SQL in Eclipse for about 2 years.  Now I want to create (alone) a pretty big community website in PHP (this program language is pretty new for me).  In this context, I found the framework TYPO3 and try to learn it.  After all I must say, that it seems very complicated to me and I can´t find the advantage over programming files strict in an normal editor without TYPO3.  I'm in an inner conflict about whether this would be good or bad for my intention to create the website.  I can´t find the benefits, but I often read, that they exist. Is Typo3 (or another framework for PHP) worth learning when you already have programming experience?

Comment: This isn't a valid question for SO. SO is for specific questions regarding programming. ie: 'here is my code, why do I get this error'. For PHP, my fav is the Yii Framework.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: Your question doesn't meet StackOverflow's requirements as it can produce many equally valid answers, here's my **opinion** from point of view of long term TYPO3 developer*:

TYPO3 is great, well known, stable tool (btw. it's a CMS, not a framework) used for building thousand of sites of different size - from small product pages to big corporate portals. It brings lot of useful techniques and technologies just out-of-the-box, login forms, contact forms, user permissions, ready to use galleries, extensions, etc, etc... so you don't need to touch every single aspect of the web-programming as you get it just right after installing the system. It does matter especially when you are gonna to work alone - when you physically won't be able to concentrate on every aspect in any sensible time. For sure you'll get benefits using it instead writing it yourself - especially with your relatively short overall experience.

But is it best choice for your needs? I don't know, nobody can know it without analyzing your concept. TYPO3 may be to heavy for the task, it's the price for its flexibility, maybe you will need to use some faster framework, i.e. (TYPO3) Flow Framework (PHP, Framework for TYPO3's originally intended successor Neos CMS), Symfony (PHP) or Play Framework (Java) which also gives you great starting point, but requires more work on every element, maybe...

The only way to determine the valid path is to compare solutions yourself or order such a comparison from a qualified agency.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 is my favorite PHP framework. When you do understand this framework, it's so easy to manipulate routing (url), mysql logic, security, etc. I use it for every project with PHP. Try it, there's ton of tutorial out there!